# Iteration: labelling multiple columns at once

Tags: r, loops, label

I need to label multiple variables at once. The basic approach I would like to use is

```
iris<–iris
attr(iris$Sepal.Length, "label") <- "Sepal Length"
```

I would like to iterate this process across all of my variables. Is there a compact way to do this?

I have created a list of variables names and labels

```
# First create my labels list.
lablist<-str_to_title(str_replace_all(names(iris), pattern = "\\.", replacement = " "))
# Second my variable names list
namelist<- names(iris)
```

But when I tried to iterate this my approach has failed: what am I doing wrong?

```
# I attempt iteration
map2(namelist,lablist,~attr(iris[,.x], "label") <- .y)
```

Ideally, I would want to use `map` for iteration, but I am open to alternative solutions if they are more compact and effective

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
replace_labels <- function(df,new_labels){
  column_names <- colnames(df)
  purrr::map2(column_names, new_labels, ~ (df[[.x]] <-`attr<-`(df[[.x]], "label", .y)))
}
iris_labelled <- iris
lablist<-str_to_title(str_replace_all(names(iris), pattern = "\\.", replacement = " "))
iris_labelled[] <- replace_labels(iris_labelled,lablist)
```

Comment: DDear Harry thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for! would you mind explaining the map2 function. I am not sure why you used `df[[.x]] <-`attr<-`(df[[.x]]` and what it means.  Thanks  a lt

Answer (score 2):

You may use `` `attr<-` `` in `Map`.

```
iris <- Map(`attr<-`, iris, "label", c("Sepal Length", "Sepal Width", 
                                       "Petal Length", "Petal Width", "Species"))

attributes(iris$Sepal.Length)
# $label
# [1] "Sepal Length"

attributes(iris$Petal.Width)
# $label
# [1] "Petal Width"
```

Answer (score 1):

**edited**: re-wrote to address change of labels instead of names

not so elegant as loops are frowned upon but works:

```r
iris_labelled <- iris

lablist<-str_to_title(str_replace_all(names(iris_labelled), pattern = "\\.", replacement = " "))
namelist<- names(iris)
names(lablist) <- namelist

for (name in namelist) {
  attr(iris_labelled[,name], 'label') <- lablist[[name]]
}
attr(iris_labelled$Sepal.Length, 'label')
```

should work (as far as I can see), but doesn't:

```r
map2(namelist, lablist, function(x,y) {attr(iris_labelled[,x], "label") <- y})
attr(iris_labelled$Sepal.Length, 'label')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I do not think your approach does what I want. The code you suggest renames my variables, while I want to label them.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your kind reply. I haven't paid enough attention